# Programmatically moving items from Junk folder to Inbox in Outlook.Interop class?

Tags: c#, office-interop, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, mapi

I am currently refining an MS Outlook Add-In to pick up emails that end up in the Junk folder with "legit" addresses and then moving them into the Inbox folder.

This is an occurence that happens a lot for Gmail addresses, and is a bit painstaking for our staff members, who have to manually link those emails to their client accounts.

Has anyone attempted this? I have registered the incoming email event handler to read the Junk folder when an email comes in, but I keep getting an exception. I suspect it has to do with the fact that some of these emails are spam; which simply means that the MailItem will have lots of errors.

Has anyone had the same issue? Here is my code:

```
public void OutlookApplication_ItemReceived(string entryID)  
{
  //this.outlookNameSpace = this.application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
  //Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox = this.outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
  //Outlook.MAPIFolder junkFolder = this.outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderJunk);

  if (Properties.Settings.Default.AutoLink || Properties.Settings.Default.EnableLeadLoader)
  {
    Outlook.MailItem mail = null;
    try
    {
      this.Log("Email detected: incoming");
      mail = this.application.Session.GetItemFromID(entryID) as Outlook.MailItem;

      this.leadLoaderRecipient = Properties.Settings.Default.LeadLoaderRecipient.ToLower();

      Outlook.Recipients recips = mail.Recipients; //That's where its crashing as the object is null... if read from spam folder

      foreach (Outlook.Recipient recip in recips)
      {
        Outlook.PropertyAccessor pa = recip.PropertyAccessor;
        string smtpAddress = pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS).ToString();

        if (Properties.Settings.Default.EnableLeadLoader)
        {
          if (smtpAddress.ToLower() == this.leadLoaderRecipient)
            this.ProcessLead(mail);
        }
      }
      if (Properties.Settings.Default.AutoLink)
      {
        this.AutoLink(mail, true);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      this.Log("Exception (ItemReceived): " + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
      if (mail != null)
      {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mail);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Looking forward to your thoughts guys! :) TIA!

Answer (score 0):

When exactly does your code run? Is that an Application.NewMailEx event handler? What is the exception?

Try to use the Items.ItemAdd event on the Junk Mail folder instead of using Application.NewMailEx.

Comment: Hi @dmitry, this is currently being implemented in a Controller I've implemented, which runs my OutlookApplication_ItemReceived event handler. The exception I get is that my MailItem is returned as a null object. This does not happen when an email is sent into the inbox.

Comment: Have you tried Items.ItemAdd event on the Junk Mail folder?